# Strange cast error with Linq and Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, linq, oracle, lambda

I am getting a cast error with Linq to a DataTable that was populated with Oracle.

```
bool isTrue = DataTable.AsEnumerable().Any
      (x => x.Field<int>("MYNUMBERFIELD") == MYNUMBER);
```

In SQL this works fine as expected.  In Oracle is fails with a cast error on the  cast.  In C# code the same thing happens when you do the following:

```
int myint = (int)VariableRetrievedFromOracleDB;
```

If you change it to `int myint = Convert.ToInt32(VariableRetrievedFromOracleDB)` it works fine.

Any ideas how to handle this with the lambda?

Comment: What's the `ClassCastException` message? Chances are, the Oracle db driver is returning the data as a string, not the appropriate native type.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isTrue = 
    DataTable.AsEnumerable()
             .Any(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Field("MYNUMBERFIELD")) == MYNUMBER);
```

Comment: That is what I thought at first too - but that still fails.

Comment: @tsells - Wait. Did MYNUMBER come from Oracle or is it defined in your code?

Comment: The underlying business object was populated from Oracle so yes it required a cast.  I modified the code as Linq had some issues here in general.